# I was trying to Replace Header with First Row in Pandas Data frame. but getting an error said: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror

I'm read a table from website using `df = pd.read_html('website link')`:

```
df = pd.read_html('w3schools.com/python/python_ml_decision_tree.asp')
df[0]
```

It successfully read the table but I want to replace the 1st row as the header.
I'm using this code:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0] 
df = df[1:]
df.head()
```

but it gave me an error that said:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f9b2cba2eb0b> in <module>
----> 1 df.columns = df.iloc[0]   #grab the first row for the header
      2 df = df[1:]               #take the data less the header row
      3 df

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

Comment: Your df is not a dataframe. It is a list. As your error is in the first line we can not resolve the problem, until you provide before lines.

Comment: In this line `df.columns = df.iloc[0] ` you are reassigning the name of the columns with whatever you have in the first row. Then you are getting rid of this first row. But as they mention above, you do not have a dataframe, you have a list there.

Comment: Please provide the URL to have a look.

Comment: @LuisAlejandroVargasRamos  
df = pd.read_html('https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ml_decision_tree.asp')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.read_html('https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ml_decision_tree.asp')
df[0].columns = df[0].iloc[0]
df = df[0][1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

[.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) returns a list. You would want to [.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) them first:

```
dfs = pd.read_html(url)
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

And finally replace headers with first row:

```
df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `df = pd.read_html('website link')`, the function `pd.read_html()` will output a list, so the variable name `df` is not suitable, and could be confusing.

Here's how I would do it, hope that it's clear:

```
import pandas as pd

lis = pd.read_html('https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ml_decision_tree.asp')
df = pd.DataFrame(lis[0]) #lis has only 1 element
df.columns = df.iloc[0]   #grab the first row for the header
df = df[1:]               #take the data less the header row
print(df)

0  Age Experience Rank Nationality   Go
1   36         10    9          UK   NO
2   42         12    4         USA   NO
3   23          4    6           N   NO
4   52          4    4         USA   NO
5   43         21    8         USA  YES
6   44         14    5          UK   NO
7   66          3    7           N  YES
8   35         14    9          UK  YES
9   52         13    7           N  YES
10  35          5    9           N  YES
11  24          3    5         USA   NO
12  18          3    7          UK  YES
13  45          9    9          UK  YES
```

Comment: Amazing man. Clear to understand. thank you.

Comment: technically `pd.read_html()` will output a list, so the variable name `df` is not suitable

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = pd.read_html('https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ml_decision_tree.asp')
```

Based on the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html):

> Read HTML tables into a list of DataFrame objects.

So:

```
type(df)
```

returns:

```
list
```

and:

```
len(df)

1
```

So,

```
df[0]
```

returns:

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   Age Experience  Rank    Nationality Go
1   36  10  9   UK  NO
2   42  12  4   USA NO
3   23  4   6   N   NO
4   52  4   4   USA NO
5   43  21  8   USA YES
6   44  14  5   UK  NO
7   66  3   7   N   YES
8   35  14  9   UK  YES
9   52  13  7   N   YES
10  35  5   9   N   YES
11  24  3   5   USA NO
12  18  3   7   UK  YES
13  45  9   9   UK  YES
```

Which is a df and you can use your `iloc`.